# Dell G5 5587 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I have two hard disks (NVMe and SATA) on my laptop and I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my machine by vendor (on NVME disk, **GPT**, `/dev/nvme0n1`), and empty SATA disk (**MBR**, `/dev/sda`) and I want to install Windows 10 on it, so I would have dual boot.

I was done it many times before, but I experience some problems on this laptop.

First, I convert `/dev/sda` from **MBR** to **GPT** using gdisk (*Windows 10 won't install on MBR at all*), then install Windows 10 on it, but whatever I do (*even if I don't install anything at all*), neither system won't boot at all, only converting `/dev/sda` back to MBR helps to boot Ubuntu again.

Could you please suggest me the procedure on how to install Windows 10 to have dual-boot on this machine?

`sudo parted -l` gives the following:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD10SPZX-75Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs

Model: KBG30ZMS256G NVMe TOSHIBA 256GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  787MB   786MB   fat32           EFI system partition  boot, esp
 2      787MB   6156MB  5369MB  fat32           Basic data partition  msftres
 3      6156MB  222GB   216GB   ext4
 4      222GB   256GB   33,7GB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
```

Comment: Windows (and Ubuntu) install in the boot mode you use for installer. So you have to boot installer in UEFI boot mode. Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt & only in BIOS mode to MBR. Your 16.04 only has a few months before EoL. Best to now  plan on update to 20.04. Post this in question above to preserve formatting:`sudo parted -l`  Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware?  Dell Precision 5820 with PCI NVME SSD UEFI update & SSD firmware update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402254

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, that your bootloader lives on /dev/sda. When you change the partition table it gets "confused" and won't load any more. I would advise:

1. First and foremost: Cover your bases! Make sure you have complete backups of your data accessible on a different system.
2. Make sure you have bootable USB stick with an image of Ubuntu handy.
3. Convert /dev/sda to GPT and install Windows 10.
4. Boot from the USB stick and run Boot Repair [as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Boot repair will automatically discover the installed operating systems and reinstall the boot loader.

Again, make sure you have a backup of all important data. (And as you'll have a USB stick with the latest Ubuntu release handy - maybe consider upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04. 16.04 will reach its end of life in Spring 2021.)

Comment: Thank you, just tried it. Approximately same result as before - neither system boot, if I try to boot partition with Windows manually through boot menu (F12) then it boots but after some time gives you information that it encountered system error cannot run. And again, converting /dev/sda back to MBR helped to restore boot as it was.

Comment: Tricky. It would be easiest to just wipe both drives, repartition them as GPT/UEFI from a live disk and then proceed to reinstall Windows and Ubuntu. You can use `gparted` which is installed by default on Ubuntu live images. (It's not that bad an idea, as you really should move to Ubuntu 20.04 anyway.)